# ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have two tables:

```
create table country(
country_code varchar2(2) PRIMARY KEY,
country nvarchar2(57) NOT NULL
);
SQL> desc airport_final
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 IATA_CODE                      VARCHAR2(3)
 CITY_CODE                      VARCHAR2(3)
 CITY_NAME                      NVARCHAR2(24)
 COUNTRY_CODE                       VARCHAR2(2)
 COUNTRY_NAME                       NVARCHAR2(33)
 NO_OF_AIRPORTS                     NUMBER(1)
 AIRPORT_CODE                       VARCHAR2(3)
 CITY_WITH_COUNTRY                  NVARCHAR2(61)
 AIRPORT_NAME                       NVARCHAR2(80)
```

When I select uique/distinct country_code then its showing 23 records:

```
 SQL> SELECT distinct(country_code),country_name from airport_final;

230 rows selected.
```

But when I try to insert these records from `airport_final` table to `country` table then:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO country(country_code,country)
SELECT distinct(country_code),country_name from airport_final;  2  
SELECT distinct(country_code),country_name from airport_final
                              *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("TESTING"."COUNTRY"."COUNTRY")
```

What should I do?

Best Regards

Comment: Any null values in airport_final?

Comment: @Berend Yes some country_names are null but all country_code exists

Comment: You have a `NOT NULL` constraint on `COUNTRY`, so `COUNTRY_NAME` (where the data is coming from) must also be `NOT NULL`.

Comment: So, there's your answer. If country name is null, you can't insert it in the country field, which is not null

Comment: @pmdba You are absolutely right. Sometime solution is in front of our eyes but we are not getting it. Thanks from the bottom of my heart

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT *
FROM airport_final
WHERE country_name IS NULL;
UPDATE airport_final
SET country_name = 'SomeDefaultValue'
WHERE country_name IS NULL;
INSERT INTO country (country_code, country)
SELECT DISTINCT country_code, country_name
FROM airport_final;
```